# Accept a list of inputs

Tags: haskell

I want to accept 5 values from the user. However, in my code (below) if I enter a list like `[1,2,3,4,5]` I get an error. This code only accepts inputs of the form `[999]`, for example.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

```
putStrLn("Enter 5 binary numbers [,,] : ")
    input<-getLine
    let n=(read input)::[Int]
    let result = convertionTO binaryToDec n
    putStrLn(show result)
```

In the above code, the line `let n=(read input)::[Int]` will just accept the user input, `[999]` or whatever, as one input. Is there a way to enter a list of values?

With the line `let result = convertionTO binaryToDec n` I'm trying to convert here list of binary values to decimal

Comment: The reading part of the code (i.e. the two lines following the `putStrLn`) works fine here. What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Uncomment the `--putStrLn (show n)`, then run your program again, and copy+paste into your question all the output, from the "Enter 5 binary numbers [,,] : " prompt onwards.

Comment: it doesn't give any error. it doesn't do what i want. what my program does is accept 5 binary numbers from the user and conver them to decimal. but i dont know how to input 5 binary number to the system ?

Comment: How is `[1,2,3,4,5]` a list of binary numbers?

Comment: recorrection [11,1011,1111,1010,10]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for the input to be converted into an `[Int]` using `read`, so it's being converted using the same rules as Haskell source code, which means they're being parsed as decimal numbers.

As you want to parse them as binary numbers, you will have to write your own `String -> Int` (or, to allow for errors, `String -> Maybe Int`) function to convert them into `Int`s from binary.

There is no distinction between decimal numbers and binary numbers. There are only numbers. Decimal or binary are artifacts of how numbers are represented as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a `newtype` wrapper around an `Integer` to give it its own `Read` and `Show` instances.  That way, you can still use the list parser, but substitute your own parser for the elements:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Numeric ( readInt, showIntAtBase )
import Data.Char ( digitToInt, intToDigit )
import Control.Arrow ( first )

newtype BinNum = BinNum { unBinNum :: Integer }
  deriving ( Eq, Ord, Num )

main = do
  putStrLn "Enter 5 binary numbers [,,] :"
  input <- getLine
  let ns = read input :: [BinNum]
      result = map unBinNum ns
  putStrLn $ show result

isBinDigit :: Char -> Bool
isBinDigit c = c >= '0' && c <= '1'

readBinNum :: ReadS BinNum
readBinNum = map (first BinNum) . readInt 2 isBinDigit digitToInt

showBinNum :: BinNum -> ShowS
showBinNum = showIntAtBase 2 intToDigit . unBinNum

instance Read BinNum where
  readsPrec _ = readBinNum

instance Show BinNum where
  showsPrec _ = showBinNum
```

Comment: I'll admit that this is a bit of a cheat, since, strictly speaking, `read` and `show` should use Haskell's representation for the type, which would be `BinNum <x>`, and not simply `<x>`.